# Rename [tab] tag to [tab-key]

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we rename [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) to [tab-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab-key) (and synonymize), so people won't tag questions about a single tab (e.g browser tab) with [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) instead of [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs)?

Comment: Are we sure that all `[tab]` questions are not about browser tabs?

Comment: Do we actually want that tag? It seems to me it causes more confusion than anything else. I just had a look at the questions tagged with it and they included posts about browser tabs, terminal tabs, the tab key, tabs in various other programs. The tag has 0 followers, perhaps it is time to nuke it to oblivion.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as my comment is getting popular, I may as well give people the chance to vote on it.

I would recommend deleting the [tab-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab-key) and [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) tags. [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) makes sense, and we could make [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) a synonym for it. Tabs are a useful GUI feature and I can imagine interesting questions that revolve around them.

The [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) and [tab-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab-key) tags seem useless to me. Why would we want a tag for a particular key on the keyboard? Granted it is one used extensively by those of us who regularly use shell autocompletion, but what kind of computer problem, that can be expressed as a question and answered on this site, would be tagged as [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab)?

I suggest synonymizing (what a horrible word) [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) and [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) and nuking [tab-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab-key).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of things tab/tabs is being used in various contexts

- browsers → [browser-tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser-tabs)
- spreadsheets → [worksheet-tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-tabs)
- vim
- indenting and formatting → [tab-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab-key) may fit best in these situations
- other application tabs such as Notepad++ tabs

As always, if you're going to retag a bunch, it's best if you also fix up other things wrong in the question. No need to bump a question and leave it fugly.