# Shred and wail on the [tab] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

My question involves a web browser, a spreadsheet, a keyboard or a sweet guitar riff..
[tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab)

In a twist of fate [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) exists - https://superuser.com/tags/tabs/info

Comment: So what, exactly, is planned?  As @Nathan2055 observed, there is a lot of varied usage.  Have we identified what tags to create or migrate the various uses to?

Answer (score 1):

Starting going through these to see if there was anything worth keeping, the tag contains extremely varied requests involving anything from tabs crashing in Chrome to doing stuff with TSV formatted spreadsheets to questions involving keyboard shortcuts using the tab key (yes, really).

It also turns out there is a [tab-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab-key). There was [a discussion](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6199/207935) early last year that seemed to come to a consensus to synonymize [tab](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab) with [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) and delete [tab-key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tab-key), which makes since to me. It might even be a good idea to rename [tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tabs) to something else to reduce confusion.

Comment: agreed. Tabs should be changed to [tag:tabbed-interface], I think.

Comment: @GauravJoseph - Yeah, that makes sense. I was trying to come up with a better tag name than [tag:tabs] but couldn't think of any offhandedly.